# Angular infdig Error When Returning Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, fusioncharts

I am new to Angular and have a situation where I must pass in an object into an attribute of an element inside an ng-repeat.  The code works fine when returning the new object if I do not use ajax to get the data and just return a plain object, however, when I do I get an infdig error.  My question is what would be the best way to do what I am doing in the code below and also resolve my infdig error.  Thanks so much in advance.

HTML element inside ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-if="currentView.comparisons !== 'null'">
    <div ng-repeat="comparison in currentView.comparisons track by $index" class="row x-margintop">
     <div class="row x-margintop">
      <div class="col-md-8">
       <fusioncharts width="100%" height="400px" type="column2d" datasource="{{getComparisonChart(comparison)}}"></fusioncharts>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 /*Ajax For Getting Comparisons Omitted For Brevity But Comparisons Will Have 
 The Following Properties*/
   var newCompObj = {name: comparison.name, template : comparison.template, dataSource: comparison.dataSource, date: {startDate: null, endDate: null}};
  $scope.currentView.comparisons.push(newCompObj);

$scope.getComparisonChart = function(chart){

//Callback and Other Chart Data Will Vary Based On The Chart Type

if(chart.dataSource === 'SvC'){
var data = [];
/* here I want to make a callback and return some data and have that data as part of the returned object.  I know this code is wrong, but not sure how to do this */
      $http({
  url:'callbacks/chart_data/dogCallback.jsp',
  method: 'GET',
  params: {startDate: chart.startDate, endDate: chart.endDate}
}).success(function(data){
    setData(data);  
});  

function setData(data){     
  return {
    "chart": {
      "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
      "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
      "xAxisName": "Month",
      "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
      "numberPrefix": "$",
      "paletteColors": "#0075c2",
      "bgColor": "#ffffff",
      "borderAlpha": "20",
      "canvasBorderAlpha": "0",
      "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
      "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
      "placevaluesInside": "1",
      "rotatevalues": "1",
      "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
      "showXAxisLine": "1",
      "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
      "divlineColor": "#999999",
      "divLineDashed": "1",
      "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
      "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
      "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
      "theme": "fint"
    },
    "data": data,
  }; 
}  
};
```

The problem is I could have many fusioncharts so I wouldn't have $scope.var for each one. The user can create any number of charts with that chart type and every chart of that type would need this same object, but will have different data.  I'm open to any ideas as to how to resolve this.  In summary, I have element that needs an object as its datasource. The type of chart defines the object and other attributes of the object I'm repeating with an ng-repeat define the parameters for the data that has to returned via a callback.  I also tried the Ajax call inline inside the object with no success.

Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Comment: The URL extension file is jsp and it seems that you want to manipulate JSON. Have you tried : "data": JSON.parse(data) ?

Comment: The data coming back is an array of JSON objects as I would expect it looks like. I even tried setting data:[] and I still get an infdig error. It looks like just the fact that I have an Ajax call inside the function is enough to cause the error for whatever reason.

Comment: You should avoid using return in a callback, it makes no sense. Don't you want to do something like `$scope.chart = { "chart" : ... }` to bind this value to your view ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I added some additional information in my question.

Comment: Can you show your ng-repeat please ?

Comment: Added some code so you could see how the ng-repeat is setup.

Comment: Can you try this : `$http` = > `return $http` ?

Comment: I added a callback inside the ajax call instead.  Still no such luck.  It seems that any ajax call inside gives me an infdig error.   Even if I set data = to an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally getting back to this question.  Not sure if this will help anyone else.  What I ended up doing is using the object with a null data object and then set the data object later after the ng-repeat completed.

```
if(startDate != null && endDate != null && (vsData != null && vsData.length > 0)){
  if(comparison.dataSource === 'svcChart'){
    $http({
      url:'callbacks/chart_data/Sales_StoreVsCountry.jsp',
      method: 'GET',
      params: {store: comparison.store, country: vsData, startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate}
    }).success(function(data){
      var chartObj = $scope.svcChart;
      chartObj.data = data;
      FusionCharts(chartId).setJSONData(chartObj);
    });
  }
}
```